# Website migrated to new server, Some Ajax no longer works

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have just migrated a website from iis6 / WinServer 2k3 to IIS7 / WinServer 2k8.

The website is .net 2.0.

On the old server it worked fine in all browsers (Tested from this PC).

Since I migrated to the new server, parts of it no longer work in ie8. But other parts of it work. In addition, the site works properly in Firefox, but it used to work properly in ie 8 previously.

So needless to say I'm very confused. Has anyone got any ideas on what might be causing this, or any thoughts on helping me track down what it is causing it?

Comment: IE has caching. Clear the cache and try again.

Comment: You must be more specific for what is not work, the iis7 have some differences, but also both iis have a lot of configuration options that may be different. So what is the problem ? more specific.

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean? Do you get an error message? Post some code.

Comment: What doesnt work is some of the ajax postbacks. What is really confusing is the fact that others do work, using the same code, but on different pages. There is nothing in the error console. And the site still works in firefox, so I'd blame it on ie8 apart from the fact that sometimes it does work.

Its all boilerplate ajax from teh AjaxToolkit so there is no real code to see (if I had something wrong in the code then it wouldnt be working anywhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be an issue on the server after all. Switching the app pool to classic not pipeline and the issue goes away.

Quote why Integrated pipeline works with all ajax apart from that in my gridview is a mystery, but I can live with it running in classic mode until we redevelop the whole site.